# AJax delete not work in some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'am trying to make an AJAx call to delete a row in table  my function work just in chrome and didn't work in IE8 nor Firefox

```
function delete_row(id)
{
  if(confirm('Confirm to delete this Equipement ?')){
 $.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'edit_equipment.php',
  data:{
   delete_row:'delete_row',
   row_id:id
  },
  success:function(response) {
    if(response=="success")
      {
    var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }
  }

 });
}
 window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reloading the page immediately after telling the browser to *start* an ajax request. That can prevent the request from being sent, or abort it if it's in progress. It also leads to a race condition between loading the new page and the deletion (if it's been received by the server) happening.

You don't need `reload` at all, since you're removing the row dynamically. Just remove the

```
window.location.reload();
```

line entirely.

But if you want to call it anyway, then don't call it until after the request has completed:

```
function delete_row(id) {
    if (confirm('Confirm to delete this Equipement ?')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'edit_equipment.php',
            data: {
                delete_row: 'delete_row',
                row_id: id
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (response == "success") {
                    var row = document.getElementById("row" + id);
                    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
                    window.location.reload(); // But again, you probably don't need it
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem that I need to reload the page to show the update on other compenents

Comment: @liane: Then just do the second thing above.

Comment: or is there any way to be sure that the request completed and then reload !!

Comment: @liane: That's what the second half of the answer shows you.

Comment: I tried it but not work  at all same thing like before